# PDF.js overrides window.print() method. How to go back to native print() method?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I am using pdf.js library from Mozilla to show PDF files. Works really great! Though, it rewrites `window.print()` method and it's actually my problem.

If I want to use printing somewhere else, where there is no element `#printContainer`, which is used in the new `print()` method to generate output for printing, I am running into problem `TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`. Of course, it's null because there is no `#printContainer` element anymore.

Have you run into such issue with this library? How would you fix that?.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried to set up your problem but there is no clue of the error you posted. It seems (to me) that print method 1 remains the same as before 2 doesn't use printContainer element. Maybe I didn't understand you, can you post the code please?

Comment: Library rewrites window.print() method. One of the views in single page application uses pdf.js. So, everything works there, but when you go to another page view (html) changes, so no more `#printContainer` element, but  window.print() method is rewritten and now it looks for this element. So, when you call the print method from a page which doesn't have `#printContainer` it breaks.

Comment: sorry, unfortunately i can't help you more than that. 
I tried this code:
   <script>
   var print_tmp = window.print;
   </script>
   <script src="/pdf.js"> </script>
   <script>
    console.log( window.print === print_tmp); // true
   </script>
and i suppose that the overwrite doesn't occur.
pdf.js library is the version is 1.6.210 and build version is 4ce2356.
https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download